# App crash due to Memory Issue in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory

In my app, I load the table view with images. There is a delete button to delete the image.

**When the images size is too big (e.g. 1.5MB) then the *app is crashed due to low memory warning.***

How can i solve this using instruments or something other solution?

How to release the object in `cellforRowIndexPath` method.

**Should i make project as ARC enabled?**

Is i make ARC Enabled project then what will be the effect?

My code for cellRow:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    for (UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    int section = indexPath.section;

    sectionItems = [sections objectAtIndex:section];

    int n = [sectionItems count];

    //NSLog(@"section items -%d",n );

    int  i=0;
    int i1=0;

    while(i<n)
    {
        int yy = 3 +i1*100;
        int j=0;
        for(j=0; j<3;j++){

            if (i>=n) break;
            Item *item = [sectionItems objectAtIndex:i];            

            //Imageview
            UIImageView *pp=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+215*j, yy*2.3, 190, 190)];
            pp.image=item.img;
            //NSLog(@"%@ %@",item.img,item.image);
            //pp.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:pp];

            //Image Button
           // CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(30+215*j, yy*2.3, 190, 250);
            CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(20+215*j, yy*2.3, 190, 190);
            UIButton *button1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
            [button1 setFrame:rect1];
            NSString *tagValue1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", indexPath.section+1, i];
            button1.tag = [tagValue1 intValue];
            [button1 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           // button1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

           //delete button..16 03 2013
            CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(176+215*j, yy*2.3, 30, 30);
            UIButton *button2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect2];
            [button2 setFrame:rect2];
            NSString *tagValue2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", indexPath.section+1, i];
            button2.tag = [tagValue2 intValue];
            [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"can.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            //button2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];


            [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
            if (isDeleting == YES)
            {
                [button2 setHidden:NO];
                [button1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            }
            else
            {
                [button1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                [button2 setHidden:YES];
            }


            i++;
        }
        i1 = i1+1;
    }

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: post your code for cellforRowIndexPath

Comment: Make sure your code is not leaking memory. Ex: Table view cell is leaking memory. Use `if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}`. Similarly check for other such leaks, resolve them. Also using ARC will not help as it is not garbage collection, app memory footprint still needs to be handled by developer.

Comment: The os has no leak here. Please fix the title

Comment: Just because an image is 1.5MB on disk does not mean that it is that big in memory. Images are uncompressed into memory, and can be many times larger than compressed versions on disk. You're generally looking at about 4 bytes per pixel for images in memory.

Comment: @BradLarson,What should i do to solve this problem??

Comment: @Amar, i tried but not working. It still crashes.

Comment: @ManthanPatel Did you fix the memory leaks in your code? If yes, please edit the code in question.

Comment: yes, i release the object after adding to subview.

Answer (score 0):

mmm... well, first of all:

```
pp 
button1
button2
```

are allocated and never released...
start to add a release for all of them just after you ad them as subView:

```
[pp release];
[button1 release];
[button2 release];
```

you current code is allocating a lot of memory everytime user scrolls, and never release...
that may fix your problem...

a step further should be to reuse objects, learn how to reuse all buttons and imageView (just set new contents for them, as images, instead of delete them and recreating them; i know that cells could have different number of buttons... but i'm sure you could manage it.. delete just overnumbered objects, that may perform better)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for (UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

try this

```
[[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

I think your coding is copying view in UIView *v and removing superView from v instead of [cell.contentView subViews]